# Allure plugin doesnt generate allure-results directory

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm, allure

I have a project with cucumber7 and junit5 tests. There is an allure plugin in my pom.xml for generating reports. I read some guides and the [official page](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm) how to set up plugin, but i still have a problem - allure doesnt generate allure-results dir and it throws the error.

The error is :
**[ERROR]** Directory C:\Users\Username\IdeaProjects\my.testing.project\target\allure-results **not found.**

I added property for maven-surefire-plugin, but it doesnt work.

```
  <name>allure.results.directory</name>
  <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.testing.project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <!--versions -->
        <junit-jupiter-engine.version>5.9.1</junit-jupiter-engine.version>
        <cucumber.version>7.8.1</cucumber.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- WebElement Wrapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlelements-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--WebDriverManager для автоматического поиска веб драйвера любого браузера  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Matchers для Assertoв -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Junit - движок для тестов -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber - BDD тесты -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Автогенерация геттеров и сеттеров -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Allure для кукумбера-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-cucumber7-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                <!--Для управления запуском тестов -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber7jvm.AllureCucumber7Jvm"
                        </argLine>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                                <value>true</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                                <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <properties>
                            <configurationParameters>
                                cucumber.junit-platform.naming-strategy=long
                            </configurationParameters>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <!--Чтобы Junit работал с плагином -->
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                            <version>1.2.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                            <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <!--Для генерации отчёта на фазе test -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                    <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <allureDownloadUrl>
                            https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.7.0/allure-2.7.0.zip
                        </allureDownloadUrl>
                        <reportVersion>2.7.0</reportVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```